# How to programmatically obtain a google cloud project number using its project id in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

A google cloud project has both a project id and a project number. How can the project id be used to obtain the project number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version of LlamaD's answer but with a query to speed up the search:

```
def get_project_number(project_id) -> Optional[str]:
    """Given a project id, return the project number"""
    # Create a client
    client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()
    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = resourcemanager_v3.SearchProjectsRequest(query=f"id:{project_id}")
    # Make the request
    page_result = client.search_projects(request=request)
    # Handle the response
    for response in page_result:
        if response.project_id == project_id:
            project = response.name
            return project.replace('projects/', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

An adaptation of sample code used in the resource manager found [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.ProjectsClient)

```
def get_project_number(project_id):
    """Given a project id, return the project number"""
    # Create a client
    client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()
    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = resourcemanager_v3.SearchProjectsRequest()
    # Make the request
    page_result = client.search_projects(request=request)
    # Handle the response
    for response in page_result:
        if response.project_id == project_id:
            project = response.name
            return project.replace('projects/', '')
```

Comment: using response.name here feels problematic despite working in all my use cases. I'd like to see if there is a cleaner solution available